# semantic versioning Gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, semantic-versioning

I am looking for a good gradle plugin that might help me manage my versioning better, since I have been relying on custom tasks and manually updating. What are the go-to gradle plugins? I tried looking around on plugins.gradle.com, but there are frankly a ton of different plugins that all seem to do the same thing.